# Positive definiteness of $\sum_{i=1}^n \boldsymbol{x}_i \boldsymbol{x}_i^\top$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\{\boldsymbol{x}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a set of $n$ *linearly independent* vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> **My question**: Is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \boldsymbol{x}_i\boldsymbol{x}_i^\top$ always positive definite, i.e. $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \boldsymbol{x}_i\boldsymbol{x}_i^\top>0$?

Clearly, if the set $\{\boldsymbol{x}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is composed by orthogonal vectors the answer is in the affirmative. What about the general case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, and the $x_i$ need not be linearly independent so long as they span $\Bbb R^n$.  For any vector $y$, we have
$$
y^T\left(\sum_{i} x_ix_i^T \right) y = \sum_{i}(x_i^Ty)^2 \geq 0
$$
so clearly the matrix is positive semidefinite.  As for positive definiteness, note that the matrix can be written as $AA^T$, where
$$
A = \pmatrix{x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_N} \qquad (N \geq n)
$$
since $A$ has full row-rank, $AA^T$ must be invertible.  Also, for the first part, it suffices to note that
$$
y^T(AA^T)y = (A^Ty)^T(A^Ty) \geq 0
$$

Comment: I agree that $\{x_i\}$ need not be linearly independent in general, but they must span all of $\Bbb{R}^n$ in order for the quadratic form to be *positive-definitive*.

Comment: It seems to me that your argument shows that the sum is positive *semi-definite*. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Jacquard you're correct.  See my latest edit, though.

Comment: @SangchulLee good catch

Comment: There are several ways to see that $AA^T$ is invertible.  Interestingly, the [Cauchy Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) expresses $\det(AA^T)$ as the sum of squares.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Great! However, I don't see the difference between the fact that the $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are linear independent and the fact that they span $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Jacquard I mean that we can have more than $n$ vectors $x_i$, and the argument still works

Answer (score 1):

To complement Omnomnomnom's answer, the condition is also necessary: if $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, then there exist linearly independent $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb R^n$ (i.e., a basis) such that $$\tag{*} A=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^{\vphantom{T}}x_j^T.$$ Indeed, by the Spectral Theorem (or Schur triangularization) it follows that 
$$
A=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j\,z_j^\vphantom{T}z_j^T
$$
with $\lambda_j>0$ and $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ a basis. Then, letting $x_j=\lambda_j^{1/2}z_j$, we get $(*)$.

Answer (score -2):

You don't use your set anywhere in the question. The sum you write is just $\Vert x_i \Vert^2$ and yes, this is always greater than $0$ as long as $x_i \neq 0$.

Comment: I don't see your point. Why is the sum equal to $\|x_i\|^2=x_i^\top x_i$?

Comment: The asker uses *column-vectors*, not row-vectors

Comment: $x^Tx\neq xx^T$...